# How to add values of checkboxes that have been checked?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

I asked this question a few days ago but I'm a beginner and no one wanted to understand what I was talking about so I'll ask again as clear as possible. I have the following check boxes, they have values. The values are their cost of the item that is on the menu. I understand that you can get a value by doing the $_POST function, but I'm not trying to echo values, I'm not trying to do the popular beginner PHP form technique of echoing the name you put in an input field. What I am trying to achieve, is to add values of the check boxes that HAVE BEEN CHECKED. So if a check box with the value of 10 is checked, and so is another with a value of 11, and another with a value of 5, I would like to echo that the price which would be 26.

I completely understand that using isset to see if a checkbox is checked and then to echo whatever you want. I am new to PHP, and one of the popular answers I got was to use the value attribute like I've done so in my code and it was quoted as " will get you 123 in $_POST['foo'] after the form was submitted, if the user checked this checkbox.". This isn't helpful, doesn't mention isset, not that that's important right now, but also only tells me it will get the 123 value if it has been checked. That doesn't achieve what I want.

I understand I could assign variable values to each checkbox, and that would be a very sweet idea, but how would I then add ONLY check boxes that have been checked??? As in add the values of checked check boxes only so that the numbers are added up, because the numbers are their values.

Please no smart answers, I've had people give me solutions in JS, & even in jQuery, and people just telling me how to just echo a value.

Again, to make it clear, I am a beginner in PHP, and I have checked over 100 different questions now and I can't find what I'm looking for. Please do not give me answers that are not in PHP, I do not want to know how to echo the value of an element, although maybe that is where I'm going wrong, maybe I don't know how to get a value, but just getting a value doesn't do anything, and it doesn't add the number values of check boxes that have been checked together to get a total price of all the food you order.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="menu.php">
<ul>
    <li>
<ul class="menus">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="edible1" value="12">Sausage Rolls</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="edible2" value="8">Fries</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="edible3" value="10">Wings</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="edible4" value="11">Spinach Pinwheels</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="edible5" value="6">Garlci Bread</li>
</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
<ul class="menus">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible6" value="18">Instant Pot Chicken</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible7" value="20">Salmon Pattles</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible8" value="23">Callco Cabbage</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible9" values="22">Bacon Wrappend Jalapeno</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible10" value="19">Potato Mash</li>
</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
<ul class="menus">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible11" value="5">Edible Cookie Dough</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible12" value="4">Ice Cream Sandwich</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible13" value="7">Cheesecake</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible14" value="3">Chocolate Cake</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible15" value="2">Brownies</li>
</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
<ul class="menus">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible16" value="5">Wine</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible17" value="5">Beer</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible18" value="5">Water</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible19" value="5">Juice</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible20" value="5">Coffee</li>
</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="order" value="Order">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS if for some reason you care about that, maybe you want to know what the form looks like in my eyes idk:

```
ul,li {
    list-style:none;
    padding : 10px;
}
  form > ul {
     display:flex;
}
```

I do not know what to do with PHP. I've made forms before adding together two input values, but what was the written values and not some given values, and it didn't have a complicated ultimatum. I am aware of using isset to echo something if something has been or not been checked, I can get a value from an input field, I can add two values together (but not numbers). I have been stuck on this for two days and so many hours have gone by I feel like at this point I must be doing something wrong that I'm oblivious to, I truly and genuinely don't know what to do.

Comment: @Fico where do you want to echo your total in HTML or in php file?

Comment: I'll most likely do it in my php file. I don't mind where the result is, I just want to learn how to do this thing lol.

Answer (score 1):

Since your checkboxes are named with a prefix of `edible`, you can loop the `$_POST` array and find elements that start with that. If you find a match, add it to a `$sum` variable. Only checked checkboxes will be sent, so you do not have to account for unchecked checkboxes.

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, "edible") === true) {
            $sum += $value;
        }
    }
    echo $sum;
} else {
    echo "POST not sent.";
}
```

Then print `$sum` as you need it.

Alternatively, you can rename all your checkboxes, where they are *all* named `name="edible[]"`, making it a "HTML array".

```
<ul class="menus">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible[]" value="12">Sausage Rolls</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible[]" value="8">Fries</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible[]" value="10">Wings</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible[]" value="11">Spinach Pinwheels</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="edible[]" value="6">Garlci Bread</li>
</ul>
```

And do this for all checkboxes.

Then you simply do

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
     $sum = array_sum($_POST['edible']);
     echo $sum;
} else {
    echo "POST not sent.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude that makes sense now. I can't believe I didn't think of using a loop, I feel so stupid now omg.

Comment: Strangely enough it's not echoing the result when I echo the value of the sum, hmmm....

Comment: Hmm. What is `var_dump($_POST);` or `var_dump($sum);` in the PHP part?

Comment: The HTML block you have above, is that called `menu.php`?

Comment: No it is called menu.html

Comment: I see. So in your `menu.php`, where do you echo the `$sum`? Keep in mind, that  `$sum` will only be defined within the condition of `if (isset($_POST['order'])) {`.

Comment: Also, I'm curious as to who downvoted. If there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know so I can improve. :-)

Comment: I copied your script and wrote echo $sum and also tried echo $value but it didnt echo anything.

Comment: I don't see any downvotes, I upvoted your answer and the up arrow is orange and its showing a 1 for the one upvote from me, same for Giso's answer.

Comment: Where did you place the `echo $sum;`? Did you dump it, `var_dump($sum);`?

Comment: I placed it after the if (strpos($key, "edible") === true) {, I'll try the dump thingy now.

Comment: `echo $sum;` must be placed after the closing bracket `}` of your `foreach` loop.

Comment: I wrote echo var_dump($sum); and it still didn't echo the sum. Weird...

Comment: See my revised answer, and see what it outputs.

Comment: It outputs a zero for some reason? That seems really strange.

Comment: Do I have to change anything in the HTML for your first script to work?

Comment: Uh, what is `var_dump($_POST);`? Put that before any other code, and see what it returns. Make sure that your form is actually sent with values checked.

Comment: It returned array(6) { ["edible1"]=> string(2) "12" ["edible3"]=> string(2) "10" ["edible5"]=> string(1) "6" ["edible7"]=> string(2) "20" ["edible8"]=> string(2) "23" ["order"]=> string(5) "Order" } 0

Comment: No I don't know what var dump post is but I can sorta see why it's useful now.

Answer (score -1):

Change the name to `name="edible[1]"`, and so on. When submitted, the values will be in an array in `$_POST`. This can then be summed up using `array_sum()`.

Comment: Thank you so much this makes so much sense now!

Comment: Just gotta get my echo to echo the sum which for some reason is not doing it atm, but I'm sure it's a quick fix.